# Game Programming

Tags: game-mechanics

Are there any major/fundamental concepts that one should know about game programming versus control driven programming?

Game Programming is event based? with a timer? An outer-infinite loop?

I come with a background of C++, Java and Ruby. I'm interested in making a basic 2D Game in Flash. Is there anything else that may be easier for me to jump into? I'm currently interested in only 2D since I don't think I'm ready for 3D.

Any great books that a interested game programmer should read?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could do with a more useful title, but I can't think of one.

Comment: Could do with a real question too. This isn't even appropriate for CW; it encompasses the entirety of game programming, which means most of the answers on the site are somehow appropriate for it.

Comment: Is a wide quuestion overall, but there are a few subquestions asked as well.

Comment: The subquestions are "What should I know about game programming?" (too general), "How does a main loop work?" (dup), "What should I start with?" (many dups of the form "Should I start with X?"), and "What books should I read?" (dup).

Comment: @Joe I don't know, "Are there any major/fundamental concepts that one should know about game programming versus control driven programming?", sounds like a reasonable question to me. Most of those questions are questions asked by people with no programing knowledge. This person is saying he is a proficient programmer, and wants to know some of the differences between application programming and game programming.

Comment: The look like questions that have already been answered around the site also. But with 4 questions in one, it fits the overly broad criteria pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring your book question, since that is answered elsewhere...

> Game Programming is event based? with a timer? An outer-infinite loop?

Typically the latter is the case, that you have an "outer-infinite loop", or [game loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure), which repeatedly updates the game state and renders to the screen.

However, in Flash, I believe they use a timer to simulate this game loop; a function is called repeatedly, and that function should update the state of your game. You don't need to redraw the entire screen in Flash, but instead you move entities and change keyframes and things like that, using ActionScript. The Flash plugin handles drawing things.

The only games that would be event-based would be perhaps puzzle games or card games. For example, Solitaire would not require a game loop rendering the screen at 60 FPS; it can just react to user input actions and draw when necessary.

Flash affords other features you can take advantage of; for example, its timeline nature means that you can implement different game screens as keyframes on the timeline (game screens being the different states of your game - main menu, game, pause screen, credits,...).

It's good that you're aiming for 2D. Flash doesn't really do 3D, and it is indeed an added level of complexity that you shouldn't have to deal with until you are clear about the game loop and other important game programming basics.

Comment: Wrt are you talking about? Seems like a reasonable question, and a reasonable answer to me...

Comment: @Joe: even if he was, it's not his fault if the system is broken

Comment: @Lo'oris: That's only if you assume "the system" is to get as much rep as possible before the site gets shut down for sucking, rather than build a useful Q&A site that won't get shut down.